# Splitting a string without separators in Lua

Tags: string, lua, split

I have written a program that decodes date codes for an old computer manufacturer. The date code consists of five digits, for example 09705. The first two digits (09) is the month, the middle digit (7) is the year and the last two digits (05) is the day. I already have all the months, day and years figured out. What I am asking is how would I split this five digit code into the 3 corresponding parts when it as entered as a whole? For example if a user enters "09705" into the program, I want to take this and split it into 3 variables so that they can be decoded. I want the user to be able to enter just the 5 digits, with nothing in-between the 3 parts. How would I achieve this in Lua, without using separators? Currently the user enters the three parts separately, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code:

```
local input = "09705"
local month, year, day = input:match("(%d%d)(%d)(%d%d)")
print("month: "..month)
print("year: "..year)
print("day: "..day)
```

[Output](https://eval.in/172737):

```
month: 09
year: 7
day: 05
```